# EF Core 5 Concurrency Issue in WPF Application with SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, concurrency, ef-core-5.0

I have been trying to troubleshoot this for a little longer than I would like to admit and admittedly this is my first time using EF Core with SQLite, but I cannot figure out what is going on. This is a .NET Core (3.1) WPF app using EF Core 5. It is a single user application. I am trying to add a new entity and this one specific entity has an issue. All of the other entities in the context add and update without any issues. Here is the exception I am getting while trying to add a new entity.

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.`

Here is my code for the entity:

```
public class SourceDataElement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }

        // Foreign key & navigation to SourceDataRow
        public int RowId { get; set; }
        public SourceDataRow Row { get; set; }

        public string StringValue { get; set; }

        public int? IntegerValue { get; set; }

        public bool? BooleanValue { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateTimeValue { get; set; }

        public Double? DoubleValue { get; set; }

        // Foreign key & navigation to SourceDataElementDataType
        public int SourceDataElementDataTypeId { get; set; }
        public SourceDataElementDataType SourceDataElementDataType { get; set; }

        public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }

        [Timestamp] public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

I created a small tester application to isolate just this entity and try different things, but I have had no luck. I can manually insert into the table in the database, but there is something with EF Core.

Here is the code I am using to create a new entity:

```
            var dateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            var newSourceDataElement = new SourceDataElement()
            {
                ColumnIndex = 0,
                RowId = 1,
                StringValue = "Test Data",
                IntegerValue = null,
                BooleanValue = null,
                DateTimeValue = null,
                DoubleValue = null,
                SourceDataElementDataTypeId = 1,
                LastUpdated = dateTimeStamp
            };

            _context.Add(newSourceDataElement);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Here is the SQL that EF Core is creating. It seems okay to me.

```
dbug: 10/18/2021 10:41:45.714 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting[20100] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p0=NULL, @p1='0' (DbType = String), @p2=NULL, @p3=NULL, @p4=NULL, @p5='2021-10-18T10:41:45.4850016-04:00' (Nullable = true) (DbType = String), @p6='1' (DbType = String), @p7='1' (DbType = String), @p8='Test Data' (Size = 9)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "SourceDataElements" ("BooleanValue", "ColumnIndex", "DateTimeValue", "DoubleValue", "IntegerValue", "LastUpdated", "RowId", "SourceDataElementDataTypeId", "StringValue")
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8);
      SELECT "Id", "Timestamp"
      FROM "SourceDataElements"
      WHERE changes() = 1 AND "rowid" = last_insert_rowid();
info: 10/18/2021 10:41:45.720 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[@p0=NULL, @p1='0' (DbType = String), @p2=NULL, @p3=NULL, @p4=NULL, @p5='2021-10-18T10:41:45.4850016-04:00' (Nullable = true) (DbType = String), @p6='1' (DbType = String), @p7='1' (DbType = String), @p8='Test Data' (Size = 9)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "SourceDataElements" ("BooleanValue", "ColumnIndex", "DateTimeValue", "DoubleValue", "IntegerValue", "LastUpdated", "RowId", "SourceDataElementDataTypeId", "StringValue")
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8);
      SELECT "Id", "Timestamp"
      FROM "SourceDataElements"
      WHERE changes() = 1 AND "rowid" = last_insert_rowid();
```

I tried adding the [Concurrency] attribute to the LastUpdated column,  I added the timestamp with insert and update triggers to populate it, but nothing seems to help. Not sure what's going on. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Hmm, sounds dumb, but have you tried to name the column `RowId` differently (e.g. `SourceRowId`) in the database table? Because criteria `"rowid" = last_insert_rowid()` in the `select` after `insert` looks very suspicious.

Comment: Ivan, thank you! That was the issue. I renamed the column and we're all good now. I can't believe I didn't pick up on that. Thanks for the second set of eyes and insight!

Comment: You're the [second person](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23918) I've seen hit this unusual case! Issue [#24835](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24835) is about using a newer syntax that would avoid the `WHERE rowid = last_insert_rowid()`